# Display a base64 image in a popup shows only part of the image?

Tags: html, image, request, base64

I need to show images in another window. I have 2 HTMLs files:

The parent HTML has a button in HTML loading pic data dynamically from a JSON object, after looping on it:

```
//JASON object loop to generate a button to open each picture in a table
```

> tabCell.innerHTML += 'value="Open picture" onclick="OpenPopup('+myBooks[[col[j]]+')" />';

In script part:

```
// open the popup and send the picture base64 image 
var popup;
function OpenPopup(picData) {

        popup = window.open("base64popup.html?picData="+picData, "Popup", "width=300,height=100");
        SendToPopup(picData);
    };

    function SendToPopup(picData) {
        if (popup != null && !popup.closed) {
        popup.focus();
        } else {
            alert("Popup has been closed.");
        }
    }

//this is the popup html file
The popup page: 
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
//on load it receive the request param
window.onload = function loadPic(){

        var pictureSource = getParameterByName('picData');
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("approval_report");

//it adds the data in HTML to show it with encoding 
        divContainer.innerHTML +='<img src=data:image/jpeg;base64,'"'+pictureSource+'"/>';

};
//function to get param
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
    </script>                       
    <body>
        <div id="approval_report" /> 
    </body>
</html>
```

This result is displaying only the first part of the image.

Any idea how to show it all?

I can change the idea of the popup also, i need to show this picture in another section then the main table.

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting of your input, but well: you should have a closer look yourself. You want to make sure that all elements are nicely written up, and that things that "belong" together use the same formatting/indenting style.